# jQuery issue: body overflow vs body margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, margin

Good day everyone!

When I click on a div I want overflow of body to become hidden and add a right margin to body of the scrollbar width. Here is my jQuery:

```
var getScrollbarWidth = function () {
    var scrollElement = document.createElement("div"); // Create element
    scrollElement.addClass("scrollbar-element"); // Apply predefined style

    document.body.appendChild(scrollElement); // Add element to page
    var scrollbarWidth = scrollElement.offsetWidth - scrollElement.clientWidth; // Subtract width without scrollbar from width with scrollbar
    document.body.removeChild(scrollElement); // Remove element from page
    return scrollbarWidth;
  };    

$(".thumbnail").on("click", function () {
    $(".project-wrap").addClass("project-open");
    $("body").attr("margin-right", getScrollbarWidth() + "px");
    $(".project-button").attr("margin-right", getScrollbarWidth() + "px");
    $("body").addClass("body-overflow");
  }
```

And css:

```
.body-overflow
  overflow: hidden !important
.project-open
    display: block !important
```

The issue is that if "$("body").addClass("body-overflow");" is in the end, it doesn't work, but if it is on the first line of thimbnail click function, then body margin is not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to store your scrollbar width in a variable before you add the `body-overflow` class.
Like:

```
$(".thumbnail").on("click", function () {
    var scrollbarWidth = getScrollbarWidth();

    $("body").addClass("body-overflow");
    $("body").attr("margin-right", scrollbarWidth + "px");
    $(".project-wrap").addClass("project-open");
    $(".project-button").attr("margin-right", scrollbarWidth + "px");
});
```